# Nativescript - unlaod frame

Tags: nativescript

I want to ask about the following:
I have 2 main frames;
app-root and dashboard.

app.js:

```
if (LS.getItem('Bearer') != null) {
application.run({ moduleName: "dashboard/root" });
} else {
 application.run({ moduleName: "app-root" });
}
```

app-root.hxml

```
<Frame defaultPage="login/login" id="app-root"></Frame>
```

app.root is first frame, it hold login and signup pages.

dashboard frame:

Login page has login button, that on tap loads dashboard page

```
var frameModule = require('ui/frame');
frameModule.topmost().navigate("dashboard/root");
```

And right now, dashboard frame is loaded. Dashboard frame has some bottom navigation that is every present and used as navigation between pages.

I also have logout button in the dashboard, that clears some data, and then navigates to login page .

And now my question / issue is - > in the login page i see dashboard's botton navigation in this page, this means that i've done something wrong i guess. As i assume that Main frame is dashboard, but why not login page ? Is there a way to "unload " dashboard frame maybe, before navigating to login page ? Of course if i slose the app and run again, logijn page looks well, there is no any dahsboard's frame elements...

Thank you for advice.

dashboard:

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="load" id="test" >
<GridLayout rows="*,60" class="c1" id="nawRows">
<Frame defaultPage="dashboard/dashboard/dashboard/" id="dashboard" class="c2"></Frame>
<GridLayout row="1" class="xx">
    <StackLayout verticalAlignment="bottom" row="2" class="bottom-nav">
        <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*,*,*,*,*,*" height="70" id="main-ic0">
            <Label class="icon0 foot-icon" row="0" col="0" tap="{{ loadPage }}"  data-id="0" id="ico0"></Label>
            <Label class="icon1 foot-icon" row="0" col="1" tap="{{ loadPage }}"  data-id="1" id="ico1"></Label>
            <Label class="icon2 foot-icon" row="0" col="2" tap="{{ loadPage }}"  data-id="2" id="ico2"></Label>
            <Label class="icon3 foot-icon" row="0" col="3" tap="{{ loadPage }}"  data-id="3" id="ico3"></Label>
            <Label class="icon5 foot-icon" row="0" col="4" tap="{{ loadPage }}"  data-id="5" id="ico4"></Label>
            <Label class="icon4 foot-icon" row="0" col="5" tap="{{ loadPage }}"  data-id="4" id="ico5"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: What you have in `dashboard-root.xml`?

Comment: <GridLayout rows="*,60" - this means that i have a navigation at the bottom, and teh pages content . Thx

Answer (score 0):

I think while logging out you must be using a wrong frame for navigating to login page. Get your `app-root` frame and navigate to login page within that.

```
frame.getFrameById('app-root').navigate('/path/to/login', { clearHistory: true });
```

Comment: Thanks, will try and inform you. But i think i did this before and it was not working. The error was - frame was not found. besides i'm afraid that getFrameById may now work as docs says :"Note that this searches for already navigated frames and won't find frames that are not yet displayed" but it's worth to check twice. Thanks.